# how to get all month of year?

Tags: javascript

As of new to javascript i am trying to get all month of a year from Jan-2014 to dec-2014 in listbox if year change to next year like 2015 then automatically a listbox to have change  like january-2015 to december-2015..so how to build this in selection box???

```
<script>
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
document.write(month)
<script>

<select name="month"></select>
```

Comment: Months in all year are same. What is the point of `particular` year? Is it that you want like `month-year`?

Comment: yes month is same but year have to change??

Comment: Since you are new it is not java script it is javascript :

Comment: fine it had been edited??

Comment: Are you looking for how to build a list of options? Refine your question please.

Comment: How many options (months) do you want to display? Starting from which date (today, January 2014...)?

Comment: Edit your question accordingly, please don't post comments.

Comment: All month from (jan 2014 to dec 2014)???

Comment: Edit your question accordingly, please don't post comments. Answer all my questions. Write full words.

Comment: Then, from jan 2014 to dec 2014, year does not change...

Comment: Still unclear, go further answering all my questions.

Comment: 1)yes, am trying to build a list of option 2)i want to display 12 month from year start 3) yes from jan 2014 to dec 2014, year does not change..after that year has to be 2015 right at the time it have to build like jan 2015 to dec 2015..like wise it go

Comment: How do you plan to do this? Is there another list box somewhere to select the desired year? Show a sample of your HTML. EDIT YOUR QUESTION RATHER THAN COMMENTING. Thanks.

Comment: no i dont have another option to select year???

Comment: I'm trying to help you actually. Please make a minimal effort. Put all these details into your question.

Comment: How does the year change?

Comment: if year come to end like December 2014 ..after that wt is year i.e 2015 so in list-box have to change like January 2015 to December 2015 like wise it go..is there possible to do without year selection if yes means do favor for me in this or else i will look up to do some other way thanks for effort

Comment: I'm sorry, no further help from me as long as the question remains as is. Try to answer these questions : How many months/years in a single list? Starting from which month/year? How does the year change? Could you write full words? Hard for me (from France) to read.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47146/discussion-between-jagan-and-wared)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <select id="year">
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
    </select>   
    <select id="month">
    </select>  

var months = new Array('Jan', 'Feb');

$('#year').change(function() {
    var optionString = "";
    for(var i=0; i< months.length; i++) {
            optionString+= "<option>" + months[i] + $('#year').val() + "</option>";
    }
    alert(optionString);
    $('#month').html(optionString);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pt3er/)

If you want to add year as per current date, you can do this:

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
```

and in `for loop` replace like this:

```
for(var i=0; i< months.length; i++) {
        optionString+= "<option>" + months[i] + year + "</option>";
}
```

Comment: y it need to select year to change month ?? its possible to do without year selection ??

Comment: Because this what you asked in your question `if year change automatically month have to change`  and also, how can you add a year in month when the year is not selected?

Comment: fine wt i mean if year changed to next year at the time month-year have to change not by selecting a year??